# How to link to a PHP file inside a Wordpress Plugin using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I'm currently trying to write a wordpress plugin. Basically it's a Form that is send to a PHP file via jQuery. (I've used the Code shown in [this Tutorial:](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/submit-a-form-without-page-refresh-using-jquery/)) Unfortunately I don't know how to link to that PHP file inside jQuery. The Problem is, that I have enabled SEO friendly URL's in Wordpress, so when I'm using the following Code:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "file.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
  }
 });
```

The Server assumes the PHP file to be located at `http://seofriendlylinktomypost/file.php` .
Hopefully someone can help me and thanks in advance =).
I'm sorry for my awful English, I hope you understood everything^^

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/making-a-plugin-file-accessible-via-url-rewrite

Comment: You should also read the [wordpress page 'ajax in plugins'](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins#Ajax_on_the_Viewer-Facing_Side).

Answer (score 0):

Create a php folder under your theme and then link in this way:

```
$.ajax({
  type    : "POST",
  url     : "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/php/file.php",
  data    : dataString,
  success : function() {
    $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also other way. Place an empty A tag with an id attribute (like `mytemplatebase`) and `href=bloginfo('template_url')` in the template, then you can use:

```
var urlBase = $('a#mytemplatebase').attr('href');
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: urlBase+"/file.php",
  data: dataString,
  success: function() {
    $('.done').fadeIn('slow');
  }
 });
```